# Using external orderby without using used query inequality in firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, geopoints, inequality

Is there anyway i can escape GeoPoint as first order in this postion?
If i remove GeoPoint from orderby it triggered the below error and if i put the GeoPoint as first orderby, as instructed as below, it mislead the second orderby priceSort..

> Uncaught Error: Invalid query. You have a where filter
>   with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) on field 'GeoPoint' and so you
>   must also use 'GeoPoint' as your first Query.orderBy(), but your first
>   Query.orderBy() is on field 'priceSort' instead.

```
 const locations=NearBy({
      center:{
        latitude:4*.*****,
        longitude:7*.*****},
      radius:30000})



    var db = firebase.firestore();
    var AdsQry = db.collection("ads");

      AdsQry = AdsQry
        .where('GeoPoint', '>', locations.lesserGeopoint)
        .where('GeoPoint', '<', locations.greaterThan)
        .orderBy('GeoPoint', 'asc');

        AdsQry = AdsQry.where('complete', '==', 'yes')
        //.where('countrycode', '==', 'IT')
        .orderBy('priceSort', 'desc')

    AdsQry.get().then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id+": priceSort="+doc.data().priceSort+" dateSort="+doc.data().dateSort);
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it like so:

```
 AdsQry
    .where('GeoPoint', '>', locations.lesserGeopoint)
    .where('GeoPoint', '<', locations.greaterThan)
    .where('complete', '==', 'yes')
    //.where('countrycode', '==', 'IT')
    .orderBy('GeoPoint')
    .orderBy('priceSort', 'desc')
```

Here's a [link to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Comment: Yes, still same result.. Please one can try it here as same as this, i want the index to order accordingly by numberic https://jsbin.com/dekafuvevo/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Have you tried creating indexes for `priceSort` in the Firebase console? AFAIK in Firestore if you want to order by a field that isn't in your where statement, you need to create an index for both `priceSort` and `GeoPoint`

Comment: No, i don't know about this option

Comment: Take a look at [composite indexes here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview)

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but still same reponse. i decided switching to elasticsearch i was trying to avoid in the project