# FireStore Multiple where query

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following firestore query below. I am trying to perform multiple 
where query on the Book collection. I want to filter by book name and book age range. However i am getting the following error

"uncaught error in onsnapshot firebaseError: cursor position is outside the range of the original query" can someone please advise.

```
           const collectionRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Books')

           collectionRef.where('d.details.BookType',"==",BookType)
           collectionRef = collectionRef.where('d.details.bookage',"<=",age)
           collectionRef = collectionRef.orderBy('d.details.bookage')


             const geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(collectionRef)

              const geoQuery = geoFirestore.query({
              center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(lat, long),
              radius: val,

              });

            geoQuery.on("key_entered",function(key, coords, distance) {   

storeCoordinate(key,coords.coordinates._lat,coords.coordinates._long,newdata)
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a chain call like `const geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(collectionRef.where('d.details.BookType',"==",BookType).where('d.details.bookage',"<=",age).orderBy('d.details.bookage'))` instead of this `const geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(collectionRef)`?

Comment: I just tried however it did not work am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Did you have the same behaviour the above solution?

Comment: yea the error message is the same as the initial  error. Are you able to replicate ?

Comment: I believe the orderBy syntax is causing the issue however i do need the order by because i am doing a filter on book age.

Comment: If you remove `collectionRef = collectionRef.orderBy('d.details.bookage')` does it work?

Comment: No, if i remove the orderBy clause it begins to complain about the <= operator.

Comment: Giving what message?

Comment: message is : "firebase Invalid query you have a where filter with an inequality on field d.details.age and must also use d.details.age as your first Query.ordeby() but your Query.orderBy() is on filed g instead" how can we remove the geofirestore orderby on the g index an if we do so how will this affect geofirestore query.

Comment: Have you also tried to use `const geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(collectionRef.orderBy('d.details.bookage').where('d.details.bookage',"<=",age).where('d.details.BookType',"==",BookType))`? See the new order? Does it work now?

Comment: the latest suggested solution did not work, it gave the initial error of"uncaught error in onsnapshot firebaseError: cursor position is outside the range of the original query"

Comment: can we remove the geofirestore OrderBy on the g field ? by default geofirestore is ordering by the g filed as the first oderby and we need d.details.age to be the first orderBy.

Comment: Give it a try. Does it work?

Comment: It didn’t work @ Alex

Comment: Do you have another error?

Comment: Your solution is the last thing I tried and it did not work i. e const geoFirestore = new GeoFirestore(collectionRef.orderBy('d.details.bookage').where('d.details.bookage',"<=",age).where('d.details.BookType',"==",BookType)). I would like to go ahead and remove the geofirestore orderBy on the g field however not sure how I can achieve that. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you create queries by adding function call step by step and see where it is going wrong.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean can you share the proposed ?

Comment: a duplicate was found at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484558/using-external-orderby-without-using-used-query-inequality-in-firebase-firestore?fbclid=IwAR2gjlRiOeRQe-7BoqQ5dV8gQ5nTPuWwCd9_10Ba3roSC87HUml6mcXIa6M however  still no real solution.

Comment: I'd check out Frank van Puffelin's response to a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50390366/error-cursor-position-is-outside-the-range-of-the-original-query#comment87800847_50390366

Comment: So micheal in a buy shell this isn’t possible at this time ?

Comment: It isn't really possible, no. Additional filters will have to take place on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Internally geoFirestore gets its results by
`this._query.orderBy('g').startAt(query[0]).endAt(query[1])`

Laying it out sequentially, expanding your `collectionRef`, something like this is happening:

```
const collectionRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Books')
collectionRef.where('d.details.BookType',"==",BookType)
collectionRef = collectionRef.where('d.details.bookage',"<=",age)
collectionRef = collectionRef.orderBy('d.details.bookage')
collectionRef.orderBy('g').startAt(query[0]).endAt(query[1])
```

The problem happens because `.startAt` is referring to your first `orderBy` which is `d.details.bookage`, so it is doing **start at the cursor where** `d.details.bookage` **is** `query[0]`.

Seeing that `query[0]` is a geohash, it translates to something like **start at the cursor where** `d.details.bookage` **is** `w2838p5j0smt`, hence the error.

---

### Solution

There are two ways to workaround this limitation.

1. Wait for an update on Geofirestore which I think @MichaelSolati is already working on.
2. Sort the results after getting results from Geofirestore's `onKey`

Comment: Unfortunately no, I will not be able to update the library to address this. But I do have other things I look to address (I just need to write tests for the library before a launch of v3)

Comment: @MichaelSolati I saw that you were working on allowing users to get a snapshot of the results without needing to aggregate them in `onKeyEntered`, that would help step 2 a lot I think. Looking forward to v3.